# Mixin in a trait into a package object twice

Tags: scala

While this works as expected:

```
trait A
trait B extends A
object C extends A with B
```

The following yields `illegal cyclic reference involving trait B` :

```
package cyclictest {
  trait A
  trait B extends A
}
package object cyclictest extends A with B
```

What´s happening there?

Comment: Try to inherit from B first. It might be that the compiler fails to linearize the base classes of the object.

Comment: @Dirk, yes indeed, too easy to think of it in the first place. Nevertheless I am still wondering if it´s on purpose or some kind of bug?!

Comment: I think your definition of a package object cannot extend traits defined in the package itself. The scala spec says: "_The package object should not deﬁne a member with the same name as one of the
top-level objects or classes deﬁned in package p. If there is a name conﬂict, the behavior of the program is currently undeﬁned._" I think what you're doing amounts to redefining traits A and B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct. The compiler resolves names `A` and `B` to the fully qualified names, so what the typechecker sees is:

```
package object cyclictest extends cyclictest.A with cyclictest.B
```

In order to check that the package object definition is correct, the compiler needs to know all the members of `A` and `B`, but in order to know that, it needs to know the members of `cyclictest` (since `A` and `B` are members of `cyclictest`). However, this happens *while defining cyclictest*, therefore you have a cycle that can't be resolved.

The first case passes because the package `cyclictest` does not inherit anything, it is the default directory-based package.